# sabre GetHotelImageRQ Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, sabre

I am using Sabre's soap api and trying to get a hotel image using GetHotelImageRQ. Here's my request xml:

```
    <GetHotelImageRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0.0">
      <HotelRefs xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/image/v1">
         <HotelRef HotelCode="0027857" CodeContext="Sabre"/>
      </HotelRefs>
      <ImageRef xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/image/v1" Type="THUMBNAIL" CategoryCode="1" LanguageCode="EN"/>
    </GetHotelImageRQ>
```

However I'm getting the following error : **Service GetHotelImageRQ:GetHotelImageRQ:1.0.0 not found**

I don't know what's wrong and My request matches the schema. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `Service` node from the envelope, or sending a null value in it.

```
<Service />
```